# Google Tag Manager - E-Commerce Tracking For Hotels

Tags: google-tag-manager

Google Tag Manager provides the example below for ecommerce tracking on multiple products. I am trying to help set this up for a hotel. Would each room be considered the different products? What would the SKU's be? Would they be made up since there's not a true product?

```
<script>
dataLayer = [{
   'transactionId'       : '1234',
   'transactionTotal'    : 38.26,
   'transactionProducts' : [{
       'sku'      : 'DD44',
       'name'     : 'T-Shirt',
       'price'    : 11.99,
       'quantity' : 1
   },{
       'sku'      : 'DD58',
       'name'     : 'Socks',
       'price'    : 9.99,
       'quantity' : 2
   }]
}];
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every room would be a separate product. You could use the same made-up string for product name and sku - there is no specified format for the sku and no need to make it different from the name. However you can use this to store different types of information, i.e use the room number as sku and the designation (if any) as name (so you could have "room007" as sku and "james bond suite" as name, that kind of thing).

Usually sku and name differ so that you have a value that's easy understandable for humans (name) and a value that easily can be fed to a backoffice system (sku) - you'd have to check with the hotel if this is necessary in your case (e.g. if they want to import GA reports into their booking system).